# Get-content password Powershell

Tags: powershell, encoding, visual-studio-code, powershell-3.0

I encrypted a password and now I need to pass my script to several computers. Not all of the users are going to have the file stored in the same path "C:\Temp" My question is how can I make get-content read from anywhere in the computer so it can read the password.txt file and the aes.key file instead of a specific path.

Here's my code:

```
$serviceActPw = Get-Content C:\Temp\password\password.txt | 
ConvertTo-SecureString -Key (Get-Content C:\Temp\password\aes.key)
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: So by doing that you are giving everyone the password and key..

Comment: It's encrypted and only internal users would use it

Comment: But you are giving everyone the decryption key...

Answer (score 0):

A better way when working with security is to, instead of distributing the actual keys and passwords in plain sight, to work with certificates.

You should really reconsider you solution as it actually provides no security at all (except providing some obfuscation).
You could just as well write the password in binhex format to keep users from reading it in plain text..
(It was **not** a suggestion ;) )